# Python searching on Google

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, google-search

I'd want to perform some search on Google, for reading last news about custom search term and I use a simple request, with `BeautifulSoup`in order to parse html.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=roger+federer&hl=en?cr=countryGB?as_qdr=y")
page = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
```

In particular, I'd want to search for only english news (GB or US is the same) but I got italian result also (I'm in Italy...).

How can I avoid it?

Eventually, is there package/API/tool written for this purpose? (I know Google closed its official API).

Comment: In the query string replace `?` with `&`.

Comment: Try this url https://news.google.com/news/search/section/q/roger+federer/roger+federer?hl=en&ned=us . Yo may use anything in place of `roger+federer`

Comment: fixed in this way: `https://www.google.com/search?q=roger+federer&lr=lang_en&cr=countryGB&as_qdr=y` ... the `?` was the problem.

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](https://policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries.  Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Answer (score 2):

To get US or UK results you can use [`gl` query parameter](https://serpapi.com/search-api#api-parameters-localization-gl) which stands for the *country to use for the Google search*.

You can also send a [`uule` parameter](https://serpapi.com/search-api#api-parameters-geographic-location-uule) which holds unique Google encoded location for the search.

Pass [query `params`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```py
params = {
  'q': 'minecraft',
  'gl': 'us',       # country to search from
  'hl': 'en',       # language
}

requests.get('URL', params=params)
```

The next problem that eventually appears is that you don't specify `user-agent`. You need to send `user-agent` which will act as a "real" user visit. When a bot or browser sends a fake `user-agent` string to announce themselves as a different client. Because [default `requests` `user-agent` is python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814).

You can read more about it in the blog post I wrote about [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46).

Pass `user-agent`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

requests.get('URL', headers=headers)
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

params = {
  'q': 'minecraft',
  'gl': 'us',       # United States results
  'hl': 'en',
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(title, link, sep='\n')
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that this code is usually easier to read, no need to maintain it over time if something in the HTML will be changed (*because of the dedicated development team that takes care of it*), figuring out how to bypass blocks from Google or other search engines.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "tesla",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",   # country to search from
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['title'])
  print(result['link'])
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.